# How to remove items and return a list when reading through a csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I trying to remove XY coordinates were the X-Coordinate is `<` 5 from a csv dataset. I then want to return those values to an X-Coordinate and Y-Coordinate list.

An example dataset is:

```
Frame,Time,P1_X,P1_Y,P2_X,P2_Y,P3_X,P3_Y,P4_X,P4_Y,P5_X,P5_Y,P6_X,P6_Y,P7_X_Y,P8_X,P8_Y,P9_X,P9_Y,P10_X,P10_Y,P11_X,P11_Y,P12_X,P12_Y,P13_X,P13_Y,P14_X,P14_Y,P15_X,P15_Y,P16_X,P16_Y,P17_X,P17_Y,P18_X,P18_Y,P19_X,P19_Y,P20_X,P20_Y,P21_X,P21_Y,Max_Length_X,Max_Length_Y,Min_Length_X,Min_Length_Y,Max_Width_X,Max_Width_Y,Min_Width_X,Min_Width_Y,Centroids_X,Centroids_Y
2,10:39.2,65.74835477,45.10031842,-2.22955167,-5.039210065,73.73594438,-3.516560206,61.90991549,41.79799446,67.06663915,-24.6161481,77.13941436,-22.98303729,-2.107068269,-3.640677541,93.94853726,3.51273869,56.51826591,28.44337707,70.2095591,11.06472095,73.07962202,-35.54419066,-2.086428541,-4.37055025,69.78626105,45.73116662,73.34402753,29.26475119,64.72901307,-40.68655635,70.90387539,6.110571001,-3.165213755,-3.189147979,70.94140139,-45.11483157,42.78164288,3.001018117,61.77394225,-1.052283362,72.07455255,38.61536724,45.73116662,69.78626105,-45.11483157,70.94140139,3.51273869,93.94853726,3.001018117,42.78164288,4.654612719,68.57005697
3,10:39.3,65.7684248,45.15534694,-2.217588519,-5.033582663,73.69043192,-3.346474054,61.69908417,41.78674915,67.18671591,-24.58808435,77.17029694,-23.02517617,-2.089248789,-3.639796897,93.89646426,3.528745627,56.5427544,28.38370261,70.19822793,10.99883442,73.1451771,-35.47750429,-2.093983308,-4.393763772,69.793868,45.85988623,73.19566664,29.30369084,64.95606388,-40.77004615,70.91007366,6.101747301,-3.185555832,-3.215378938,71.04051167,-45.29294224,42.83526579,3.015121968,61.82365038,-0.992786137,72.11546062,38.71278829,45.85988623,69.793868,-45.29294224,71.04051167,3.528745627,93.89646426,3.015121968,42.83526579,4.667858823,68.58636106
4,10:39.4,65.7834979,45.23761992,-2.197449449,-5.035404033,73.63024857,-3.170554247,61.69908417,41.78674915,67.31838918,-24.56060698,77.19810461,-23.05487575,-2.071445915,-3.639921113,93.83429634,3.549376049,56.58563081,28.31338862,70.20044679,10.91910555,73.19935612,-35.41010968,-2.095319355,-4.403124715,69.793868,45.85988623,73.03211884,29.35832821,65.18572736,-40.83631919,70.90862232,6.095069866,-3.216179674,-3.264310703,71.14518241,-45.50045784,42.91278516,3.042026157,61.89316922,-0.908282198,72.15835354,38.79647675,45.85988623,69.793868,-45.50045784,71.14518241,3.549376049,93.83429634,3.042026157,42.91278516,4.677460036,68.61640478
5,10:39.5,65.77840928,45.33358677,-2.161247597,-5.05651654,73.56738903,-3.004921009,61.49273767,41.78345615,67.45296434,-24.49742142,77.24683185,-23.0746477,-2.066135788,-3.642729422,93.75341377,3.57316934,56.58563081,28.31338862,70.21321398,10.82616678,73.24568774,-35.32805879,-2.081004291,-4.382976671,69.76596819,46.01111858,72.86184401,29.42608261,65.44690548,-40.85525672,70.89755931,6.089554125,-3.244595089,-3.323271171,71.14518241,-45.50045784,43.00642078,3.080217618,61.97555301,-0.809576222,72.19068707,38.85755563,46.01111858,69.76596819,-45.50045784,71.14518241,3.57316934,93.75341377,3.080217618,43.00642078,4.719056266,68.62508228
6,10:39.6,65.77840928,45.33358677,-2.131061868,-5.101371801,73.50806135,-2.855633447,61.3237999,41.7645154,67.45296434,-24.49742142,77.31339655,-23.08972129,-2.08426781,-3.655312799,93.64174988,3.597532195,56.65025238,28.22321974,70.23114884,10.71566289,73.2926943,-35.21882915,-2.055359801,-4.335811297,69.71782002,46.17421599,72.68560842,29.51043513,65.74782799,-40.84255022,70.87891012,6.077805367,-3.264717347,-3.378809476,71.23816153,-45.7142832,43.10742527,3.116367715,62.05509887,-0.701754721,72.21717228,38.89813378,46.17421599,69.71782002,-45.7142832,71.23816153,3.597532195,93.64174988,3.116367715,43.10742527,4.734781266,68.63767655
7,10:39.7,65.75014637,45.43899962,-2.13707627,-5.151010737,73.50806135,-2.855633447,61.19700699,41.7258644,67.58915846,-24.37106504,77.38130274,-23.10307092,-2.109576279,-3.667333068,93.51787893,3.634328031,56.72537119,28.09054972,70.24967103,10.59080123,73.2926943,-35.21882915,-2.033843643,-4.294642881,69.67960579,46.33094215,72.49404407,29.59751202,66.06115669,-40.83993114,70.86080027,6.05285653,-3.281122633,-3.426029656,71.31336268,-45.90846101,43.2195678,3.144570182,62.12609805,-0.586598609,72.25515393,38.91940055,46.33094215,69.67960579,-45.90846101,71.31336268,3.634328031,93.51787893,3.144570182,43.2195678,4.743660889,68.66006357
8,10:39.8,65.72415694,45.5638032,-2.18452537,-5.199475046,73.44657692,-2.72192294,61.080345,41.70838991,67.71533117,-24.18657972,77.44308531,-23.11845241,-2.125562571,-3.669284234,93.38796245,3.688287535,56.79638669,27.90929345,70.27002355,10.45441014,73.34211471,-35.08260266,-2.02916943,-4.285670767,69.65662456,46.47998758,72.27043085,29.67176654,66.35939869,-40.86560837,70.8555952,6.011435456,-3.302207775,-3.468207462,71.3879848,-46.08573746,43.35090951,3.165650171,62.19517251,-0.469470394,72.29242686,38.92721258,46.47998758,69.65662456,-46.08573746,71.3879848,3.688287535,93.38796245,3.165650171,43.35090951,4.767638977,68.68085445
9,10:39.9,65.72415694,45.5638032,-2.236354171,-5.245607807,73.34321435,-2.484931546,60.96876103,41.71902907,67.91714413,-23.76286234,77.50996588,-23.13078797,-2.134325919,-3.66977653,93.2338117,3.747387513,56.79638669,27.90929345,70.30195937,10.30869873,73.40204147,-34.76055633,-2.045150883,-4.306150842,69.63899826,46.62648261,72.01016239,29.73848462,66.61697312,-40.93431941,70.84946964,5.956736242,-3.328425867,-3.49150577,71.3879848,-46.08573746,43.50531444,3.182638905,62.26571559,-0.349540463,72.306823,38.92576468,46.62648261,69.63899826,-46.08573746,71.3879848,3.747387513,93.2338117,3.182638905,43.50531444,4.833504912,68.69287546
```

I read the csv file as such:

```
with open('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv') as csvfile :
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV :
        if n == 0 :
            n+=1
            continue
        x_data = []
        for player in ([float(row[2]),float(row[4]),float(row[6])]):
            if player < 5:
                continue
            else:
                x_data.append(player)
        visuals[0].append(x_data)
```

This provides me with a list of X-Coordinates > 5.

When I export the list the columns get shifted whenever values are removed. Below is an example of the exported X-Coordinates. E.g. Player 2 X is removed from the list until it's above 5. This is fine but instead of being blank until it meets this function, Player 3's X-Coordinate is shifted left?

List Output:

```
Player 1_X  Player 2_X  Player 3_X
67.32213473 69.95692546 
67.30126517 69.90505068 
67.28604137 69.83347832 
67.27140091 69.7662355  
67.26373215 69.72997973 
67.28158751 5.294844117 69.72595034
67.32005993 5.721823825 69.73204207
67.36659395 6.155413991 69.72947318
67.40717007 6.58302186  69.71798806
67.42824027 7.001268674 69.69067463
67.44179872 7.437058638 69.64537185
```

It should read:

```
Player 1_X  Player 2_X  Player 3_X
67.32213473             69.95692546 
67.30126517             69.90505068 
67.28604137             69.83347832 
67.27140091             69.7662355  
67.26373215             69.72997973 
67.28158751 5.294844117 69.72595034
67.32005993 5.721823825 69.73204207
67.36659395 6.155413991 69.72947318
67.40717007 6.58302186  69.71798806
67.42824027 7.001268674 69.69067463
67.44179872 7.437058638 69.64537185
```

This issue is repeated whenever a player's coordinates are removed. Basically, the empty rows don't stay empty. The data is shifted from the right to fill these empty rows?

Comment: Can you elaborate the requirement a bit? Maybe a sample output.

Comment: Make your player variable loop over a tuple of tuples of rows (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7) and check if player[0] >= 5 then append the player to your data list.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more @BoboDarph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the Y coord at the same time as the X coord:

```
with open('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV:
        if n == 0:
            n + =1
            continue
        x_data = []
        y_data = []
        for (x,y) in [(2,3), (4,5), (6,7)]:
            xcoord = float(row[x])
            if xcoord >= 5:
                x_data.append(xcoord)  # all xcoords >= 5
                y_data.append(float(row[y])
        visuals[0].append(x_data)
```

btw, I removed the redundant `if xcoord < 5: continue`

Comment: This may have to be another question @quamrana but I'm having trouble with the output of the code. The code removes the XY data < 5. But the resulting list doesn't keep the same column structure. Using the above csv file, Player 2's XY data is removed but instead of being blank, Player 3's data is shifted to the left. When Player 2 is > 5, Player 3 then shifts back to the appropriate column. Any reasons why this would occur?

Comment: Well, the result does not contain *any* information about players with xcoord <5. Maybe you need to add some dummy data in an `else:` clause.

Comment: I've provided more info in the question. Would I say `else:` `''` or `continue`

Comment: No, of course not, it would be like: `else: x_data.append('invalid')`

Answer (score 3):

slice your row and map into 2 variables using `range` to issue values 2,4,6. Compare x coordinate, add coordinates to list if matches:

```
for px,py in (row[i:2+i] for i in range(2,7,2)):
    px = float(px)  # avoid multiple float conversions for px
    if px < 5:
        continue
    else:
        # convert py to float only if needed
        xy_data.append([px,float(py)])
```

Comment: Would be useful to explain the use of range there, or more comments on intent.

Comment: I have thought about this same answer. I guess it will work as OP asked. upvoted

Comment: Exactly ...who ever downvoted may not be understand the full question

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas we can do it easily like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
widexy= pd.read_csv("Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv")
#add every x values then new row is X-Coordinates 
Check = widexy[X-Coordinates>5]
updatedYCoord = widexy[Y-Coordinates][Check]#This will give the output
```

Comment: There seems to be missing some `"` signs -- did you try to run this code?